# Create global variables for limited hardware resources, but with private constructor

Tags: c++, global-variables

I'm developing a C++ library for an embedded device. I want to create classes to handle some hardware resources such as UART peripherals.

What I want to do is to offer some global variables, for example UART1 and UART2. But I also want to keep the constructor private, because it makes no sense that the user can create a new instance for an UART that doesn't exist, or even worse, duplicate one of the existing one and trying to access it from 2 different objects.

The problem is that I can't access to the private constructor when defining them outside the class, like this.

```
// uart.h
class Uart {
private:
   Uart(int uart_num);
}

extern Uart uart1, uart2;

// uart.c
Uart uart1(1);
Uart uart2(2);
```

What would be a good way to achieve this? I've been thinking about an static method like `Uart &get_instance(int uart_num)`. This is not a bad option, but I like more the global variables for this, I see them cleaner and more elegant. If this is the best solution, should I return a pointer or a reference to the uart object?

I've also thought about static members of the class, but this makes too long strings to access the variables. My library is inside its own namespace so the user would have to access it writing `mylibnamespace::Uart::uart1`, instead of `mylibnamespace::uart1`. This is neither a bad solution, but I still prefer the global variables one.

Comment: You're looking for a factory, essentially what you described in your `static` method part.

Comment: You can declare a friend function - which can then access your private constructor - and have that function as your factory (if that meets your needs.)

Comment: You can always have static functions, and then you add a wrapper in the parent scope, to avoid friend.

Comment: Depending on the information you want to share, you could use "get-apis" instead of public variables.

Comment: @Rags that doesn't work because when defining the variable default constructor is called, and it's private. It should work with pointers and allocating in the heap, I supose.

Comment: @MatthieuBruche and Jose, I don't know what you mean, could you explain a bit more, please?

Comment: @naggety Indeed - returning a pointer (depending on your usage, a std::unique_ptr or a std::shared_ptr) is absolutely how it can be done. I would avoid a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a full answer. I will avoid using friend declaration here.

```
class Uart {
public:
    static Uart& get(int uart_num);
   Uart(const Uart&) = delete;
   Uart(Uart&&) = delete;
private:
   Uart(int uart_num);
}

// This is the function you can use from the outside
Uart& get_Uart(int uart_num);

Uart Uart::get(int uart_num)
{
    Uart uart0(0);

    switch(uart_num):
    {
        case 0:
            return uart0;
    };
    throw std::out_of_range("no such UART");
}

Uart& get_Uart(uart_num)
{
    return Uart::get(uart_num);
}

Uart& foo = get_Uart(foo_num);
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirements because this way new instances can be constructed calling Uart::construct from anywhere. The same would happen using friend declaration because the friend function must be global.

Comment: Thanks for the effort of offering a solution, but it doesn't answer the question. What I need is a public API which doesn't offer the chance of creating new Uart instances, but just use the public methods of some already created Uart instances.

Comment: OK, let's try something else then.

Comment: The good aspect of the static variables inside the getter is that you don't have any initialization race. You can enforce the order in which they are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it is better for you to use global variables, I would use something more dynamic with pointeres or the factory solution suggested above. But, anyways, The only way I see to provide global variables with no constructor (or private) is creating from an inherit class using default copy constructor. Since this is not a pointer or a reference you should be very carefull, this UartPriv::UartPriv(int) constructor is just to fill Uart member variables, not additional methods or variables should be declared here.

```
// uart.h
class Uart{ 
};

Uart uart1, uart2;


// uart.c
class UartPriv : public Uart{
public:
    UartPriv( int uart )
    {
        //initialize Uart members here
    }
};

Uart Uart1 = UartPriv( 1 );
Uart Uart2 = UartPriv( 2 );
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work because I have to delete the move and copy constructors to avoid other instances to be created anywhere, so it doesn't work.